# Milky Way cover that is (subliminally) a female image

Tags: story-identification, novel

This book was one I read in the 80s. It was printed about 1970. It was about a male slave who escapes with his female master, IIRC. Obviously it was science fiction.

The front of the book had the title words on a starry background what, when you looked at it in a certain way, would look like a female figure. Of course, I was 15, so that was easy for me.

The back cover, or perhaps inside the sleeve, was a picture of the author in a suit with bookshelves behind him.

The book may or may not be any good. But when I was a kid, I liked it.

Comment: All your title makes me think of is [this Monty Python clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yq4uCWtQE24).

Comment: This makes me think of the artist Virgil Finlay, he made a lot of images like that, and was know for his depiction of women.  Do you remember if the book was in black and white or color.  A quick search revealed this image, which seems similar to what you are looking for: http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/f/f3/THTHRDBKFV1978.jpg